# Float based design with 3 columns and x rows and div addition compatibility

Tags: html, css, layout

I have been having this issue for quite some time, but i'm unsure how I should word it. I apologize in advance if my title is vague/not descriptive enough.

I'm attempting to create a page, where its is three columns wide and the center column has a fixed spacing between the left and the right div.

I'm looking for behaviour similar to the figure below, where the addition of a new div at the top left corner, pushes all of the divs to the left and also keeps the spacing with the center column.

```
|[div] [div] [div]|         |[new] [div] [div]|
|[div] [div] [div]|         |[div] [div] [div]|
|[div] [div] [div]|         |[div] [div] [div]|
|[div] [div] [div]|         |[div] [div] [div]|
|[div]            |         |[div] [div]      |
|                 |
```

My best idea was to add spacing-divs, unfortunately this causes an issue with the margins. Since the spacing divs just get pushed.

```
|[div] [div] [div]|         |[new] [div] [div]|
|[div] [div] [div]|         | [div] [div]     |
|[div] [div] [div]|         | [div] [div]     |
```

I attempted to do some css where the right-hand margin would absorb the the spacing div, but I couldn't get anything to work.

I appreciate any kind of feedback. If something is unclear about my question, feel free to ask for some more information.

(https://jsfiddle.net/871tw4e7/)

Comment: could you set up a jsFiddle for your problem? It will help us work out the issue

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/871tw4e7/
It's this kind of layout im looking for. Then If you want to add a new div to the top left corner, everything moves and looks the same (with the same center column spacing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by using nth-child.

```
a:first-child .child, a:nth-child(3n+1) .child{
    margin-left:0;
}
a:nth-child(3n) .child{
    margin-right:0;
}
```

This allowed me to remove the margin from the first and every fourth element and also remove the right margin from every third.

This creates a layout where it is possible to add a new div to the top of the page, and still retains the desired layout.

Here's a fiddle showing the results I was looking for.
https://jsfiddle.net/9v7h4od5/

Initially I also had some issue with the nth-child, because I didn't take into consideration that when the anchor tag was added it replaced the div as the child to the parent container.